# Can apache camel support the telecom diameter?

Tags: apache-camel, telecommunication, diameter-protocol

all.

I am considering for real-time data traffic diameter interface on telecommunications.
I want to use apache camel for the interfaces.

Can camel support this industry?
Mobile service for data require diameter protocol including gy, ro, so and so on.

I can’t judge about this issue.
Please advice to me.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean [that diameter protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter_(protocol))? Technically I don't see any reason why this shouldn't be possible, but I also don't know any implementations of it yet. Apache Mina supports TCP and SCTP (since 2.0.8) so you could build your component on top of Apache Mina or use Camel's Mina component to receive arbitrary streams and process them within your route logic

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Additionally, OCS(online charging system) with diameter protocols need high performance for 5g. Can you judge that apache camel is appropriate? May I try to implement a prototype for this domain?

Comment: Apache Camel is just an integration framework with [lots of supported components](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components). All it does is to take input from consumer components, such as Mina, Files, ... and passes it along the beans, processors, ... you defined in your routes. It is unclear whether you want to take some kind of input stream received via Mina and process the payload inside of a Camel route or if you want to write your own component that just passes preformated messages to the Camel routes, which may be easier to process by other components.

Comment: In 5g era, mobile traffic of online charging system will provide the data by https protocols. Virtually, in my scenario this data will be coming from endpoint like http2 component. this data will transform to diameter data, and rating system will be received and return response to camel endpoint synchronize. I wanted to know if this was a possible scenario or not considered.

Comment: As mentioned, technically this should be doable. Camel does have a couple of components that can work on HTTP/2 such as undertow, jetty or netty. If you need to convert the payload to diameter you might want to read up on Camel's [type converter](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/type-converter.adoc)

Comment: Thank you for kind comment. I will try to implement this scenario simple.

Comment: Diameter uses a request-response messaging pattern, so is a good fit for Camel.  I implemented a Camel Diameter component and several other telecoms protocol endpoints for a previous employer a few years back.  It took a reasonable effort to implement Diameter because no suitable java implementation was available at that time.  There is a fair learning curve to using camel & writing async Camel endpoints.  Using Camel and servicemix had advantages compared with using straight java as we had been doing previously.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also think that diameter interfaces are fine by using camel. But I was worried that camel had such performance issue about this online traffic with diameter.